# login with facebook open in Android facebook Application in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I was implement login with **Facebook in PHP** It's perfect Works But i want if website open in mobile browser then redirect in **Mobile Facebook Application** if Not then mobile browser. How can Do ?

here some code

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; // download official fb sdk for php @ https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([

  'app_id' => '*****************',

  'app_secret' => '*******************',

  'default_graph_version' => '***',

  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$loginUrl = $helper2->getLoginUrl('URL', $permissions);

//here login with facebook button

<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>" class="fbblue">Log in with Facebook!</a>
```

This code redirect only facebook in browser.

Help me .

Thnakyou

Comment: *i want if website open in mobile browser then redirect in Mobile Facebook Application if Not then mobile browser*, Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @Dlk  Thank you For Answer! But I want open in Facebook Application  .

Comment: You can not combine the web login with the native apps.